# Math French Words

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

I am trying to read some papers on Algebraic Geometry in French. But I am stuck in understanding some Math.French.Words. Anybody has a good reference for it?

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't know of any such references. I wonder if this site could not be a very good place to collectively produce a lexicon with a list of french words and their english translations (and comments that are helpful, for example to signal slightly different uses, or tricks
to remember the translations). Their should be just one answer, of course in community wiki, and each user would edit it to add words 
at their right place for the alphabetic order.

Comment: Otherwise, for a more limited answer, it would be helpful, Sina,
if you could tell us more about the type of words that are problematic. Depending on for linguistically background, they may be very different. Are you a native english speaker? do you know Latin? Greek?



Comment: For a start see for example here http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~reyssat/dico/dicofa.html . A general method I find helpful is via wikipedia; for somewhat standard things it works quite well: go to the page of the object or related one and then change the language.

Comment: @Joël: This site is *not* a good place for creating and in particular maintaining something like this. 

Comment: Get French and English copies of the same edition of some book on an algebraic geometry topic (use the Internet or a library) and go through both books with a dictionary at your side to make your own list of French algebraic geometry technical words and key ordinary French words arising in math discussion ("either...or", "if...then...", "Let", etc.) that *don't look very similar* to their English counterparts. Such a list is shorter than you might imagine, and so is a practical way to acquire the skill you seek.

Comment: As said by Joel, your linguistic background is important. If your background is english or german, I would say that a standard french dictionary from a bookstore is sufficient, because the mathematical vocabulary is really very similar and for the words that are not so similar one can usually puzzle it out from a standard dictionary. Reading Bourbaki in this manner is an excellent way to learn mathematical French. That's how I learned it, anyway, although I must admit that it was not good enough for passing my French language exam at Princeton on the first try......

Comment: A useful book in that regard is the bilingual edition of the Grothendieck-Serre correspondence (from 1956-1964): lots of typical french sentences, and technical math words, translated carefully side by side. A few more recent technical words are thus missing, to be found online. The book is edited by the AMS, and a preview is here http://books.google.fr/books?id=FBfygannPSUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: It is important to note that "ignore" and "expose" do not have the same meaning as they do in English. In particular, I find expose quite difficult to translate. Also, "croissant" means "increasing".

Comment: Another possible approach is first read a paper or book about math you already know.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Kai-Wen Lan has written a glossary for French and German. Quoting from his [web page](http://www.math.umn.edu/~kwlan/academic.html) "These are prepared primarily for reading mathematical texts". You can find the French one [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~kwlan/documents/french-glossary.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Ricky. Your answer was very helpful. Also, thanks others for their help.

Comment: The term VERSEURS is not listed, Help from a 1946 paper by Lamaitre on Quaternions

Comment: That one is actually quite easy: [versor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor). @RichardLAmoroso

Answer (score 16):

I have given a 3-hour course trying to help mathematical students with an English background to read papers in French. You can find notes [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~jbellaic/French.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Please notice a few differences between French and English. "Un nombre positif" is a non negative number, "supérieur à" is "greater than or equal to". In English 0 is not a natural number, while in French it is "un entier naturel". A stack is "un champ", while a field is "un corps (commutatif in rather old texts, now what we used to call 'un corps non commutatif' has become 'une algèbre à division'). Finite fields were first known as "champs de Galois". A linear or vector space is always "un espace vectoriel". A covering is "un revêtement", a map "une application", and both manifolds and varieties are "variétés". A set is "un ensemble". An abstract is "un résumé", but abstract structures are "structures abstraites". And both groups and music bands are "groupes"!

Comment: Fascinating, and helpful. What is the French for “a positive number”?

Comment: The meaning of "positive" and of "natural number" is certainly _not_ a matter of language.

Comment: @FredRohrer I agree it shouldn't be, but practically it's unfortunately more or less the case

Comment: @RobinHouston: "un nombre strictement positif." Same construction for greater "x est strictement superieur a y" (I dropped some accents for ease of typing).

Comment: @FredRohrer: I wasn't aware there is full consensus on whether the naturals include 0 even in the _English_ language literature.

Comment: Indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: @Willie: That is not what I meant. The meaning of such terms depend on the authors' choice of a definition, often influenced by their "school", and of course sometimes by their language.

Comment: @FredRohrer: Ah, I see. It seems I (and possibly also YCor) read into your comment the opposite meaning as you had intended.